# How to safely save and load sympy objects

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

Is there an official way to safely save and load sympy objects (for sending over the internet)?

using `np.save` and `np.load` give the following exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSave.py", line 19, in <module>
    print np.load("out.npy", out)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 415, in load
    if mmap_mode:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py", line 195, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

I was considering using `srepr` turning `Eq(5*x + 12 - 8, 12*x - 10)` into `Equality(Add(Add(Mul(Integer(5), Symbol('x')), Integer(12)), Integer(-8)), Add(Mul(Integer(12), Symbol('x')), Integer(-10)))` but as far as I know the only way to load it in from text was to use `parse` but I would prefer not to exec strings from the internet.

This is diffrent that the question [SymPy: Safely parsing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131128/) as I am ok with binary formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pickle` seems to work

For `h1` (from a previous SO question):

```
In [52]: h1
Out[52]: -exp(Abs(sqrt(x**2 + y**2)/pi - 1))*Abs(sin(x)*cos(y))
In [53]: type(h1)
Out[53]: sympy.core.mul.Mul

In [47]: import pickle
In [48]: pickle.dumps(h1)
Out[48]: b'\x80\x03csympy.core.mul\nMul\nq\x00csympy.core.numbers\nNegativeOne\nq\x01J\xff\xff\xff\xff\x85q\x02Rq\x03}q\x04bcsympy.functions.elementary.complexes...PRqQ}qRb\x86qSRqT}qUb\x86qVRqW}qXb\x86qYRqZ}q[b\x85q\\Rq]}q^b\x85q_Rq`}qab\x87qbRqc}qdb.'

In [50]: with open('text.txt','wb') as f:
    ...:     pickle.dump(h1,f)
    ...:       
In [51]: with open('text.txt','rb') as f:
    ...:     print(pickle.load(f))
    ...:     
-exp(Abs(sqrt(x**2 + y**2)/pi - 1))*Abs(sin(x)*cos(y))
```

`np.save` resorts to `pickle` if it can't save the object as an array, but apparently using `pickle` directly is more reliable.  `sympy` objects do not inherit from `numpy` (at least the basic ones don't).

`pickle` depends on the `sympy` class defining its own encoding/decoding functions (I forget the name).

Comment: Note that while this answer is correct, it does not address the initial intention. Pickling is not safe, and therefore if the goal is to avoid unsafe execution, pickling doesn't bring extra security.