# Sympy: reducing custom function as string with sympify?

Tags: python, sympy

**Is there a solution to sympify() strings including custom methods?**

Sympy has the beautiful function `sympify`.

- It can reduce strings to sympy-functions **and** reduce all expressions. Nice!
- It allows to add 'sympify'-able functions as class.

This is the official example.

```
from sympy import Matrix, sympify

class MyList1(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        yield 1
        yield 2
        return
    def __getitem__(self, i): return list(self)[i]
    def _sympy_(self): return Matrix(self)


local_dict= {"MyList1": MyList1}
print(sympify(MyList1()))    # Matrix([[1], [2]])
print(sympify('MyList1()'))  # MyList1()
print(sympify('MyList1()', locals=local_dict))  # <__main__.MyList1 object at 0x0000000006D0AA20>
```

The last two lines can not be reduced by sympify- our class is obviously not known when sympifying a string. Putting the class into 'locals' did not work for me.

Is there a solution to reduce strings?

---

- [Need sympy function for log2(x) capable of being used in sympy.solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223486/need-sympy-function-for-log2x-capable-of-being-used-in-sympy-solve) did not work for me
- [SymPy: Safely parsing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131128/sympy-safely-parsing-strings) was not solved
- Also: In https://stackoverflow.com/a/58487317/5626139, the class type was id `Function` and not `Object`. Which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this to be a bug in SymPy. Basically, it isn't calling `_sympy_` when it constructs an object from a string. You can work around it by either calling `sympify()` twice, like `sympify(sympify('MyList1()', locals=local_dict))`. Under normal operation sympify() should be idempotent so there is no harm in doing this.

Comment: I opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17785 for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think it did what you wanted...MyList1 doesn't have a method for printing but the data is there:

```
>>> list(sympify('MyList1()', locals=local_dict))
[1, 2]
```